# Python comparing a number to a value in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, valueerror

I want to count the number of zeros in a dataframe but doing so using a for loop and if statement gives me following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

[My code to count the number of zeros in a Pandas dataframe giving error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iq6JZ.png)

[image]

Comment: Please post the actual code, not an image. Also your code should be a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get that error is because `df.iloc[i]` returns a series object and `df.iloc[i]==0` returns another boolean series such as `[True, False, True, True]`. That's why instead of getting a single True or False value for the if condition, you end up getting a series of boolean (*which might be a single length series as well if there is only 1 column!*) which in turn throws that error.

Based on the code that you provide, it seems you can simply do the following instead. But please post your dataset to help others understand what you are trying to do.

```
k = (data2==0).sum().sum() #sum row-wise, then sum column-wise
```

This creates a dataframe with boolean values everywhere there is a 0, and the first sum returns the number of True values (because True is equal to 1 and False is equal to 0) per row. The second sum then reduces it to the total number of 1s in the dataframe across all rows.

---

Other ways you can do this is -

```
(data2==0).values.sum()

#OR

(data2==0).to_numpy().sum()
```

---

If you still want to use the loop (maybe because you want to do more complex tasks), you will have to iterate the rows and then each value in the row series (columns) of the dataframe as such -

```
k=0
for i in range(data2.shape[0]):
    for j in range(data2.shape[1]):
        if data2.iloc[i,j]==0:
            k+=1
```